# Issue while connecting ESP8266 with Arduino Mega. It always says "Module have no response."

Tags: arduino, embedded, wifi, robotics, esp8266

I am having Issue while connecting ESP8266 with Arduino Mega. It always says "Module have no response."

Please check and correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

I am using below code and and wiring diagram is 
[image]

My Code:

```
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
   //use mega Serial 2 for serial monitor; Serial 1 on pins 19 (RX) and 18 (TX);// Serial2 on pins 17 (RX) and 16 (TX), Serial3 on pins 15 (RX) and 14 (TX).
   #define SSID "SopraSteria"
   #define PASS "1234567890"
   #define DST_IP "220.181.111.85" //baidu.com
   //SoftwareSerial dbgSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
   void setup()
   {
     // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
     //serial 2 is to esp8266 
     Serial2.begin(9600);//9600 (mine), 57600, 115200
     Serial2.setTimeout(2000);

     //serial 0 is to usb
     Serial.begin(115200);


     while(!Serial); 
     while(!Serial2);

     //dbgSerial.begin(9600); //can't be faster than 19200 for softserial
     //dbgSerial.println("ESP8266 Demo");
     Serial.println("ESP8266 Demo on Mega2560");

    while(Serial2.available()>0)
    Serial2.read();

     delay(1000);
       //test if the module is ready
     Serial2.println("AT+RST");
     //delay(1000);
     //delay(1000);
     Serial.println("Resetting module");
     Serial2.flush();

     //if(Serial2.find("ready"))
     if(Serial2.find("Ready")||Serial2.find("ready"))
     {
       //dbgSerial.println("Module is ready");
       Serial.println("Module is ready");
     }
     else
     {
       //dbgSerial.println("Module have no response.");
       Serial.println("Module have no response.");
       //while(1);
     }
     delay(1000);
     //connect to the wifi
     boolean connected=false;
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
       if(connectWiFi())
       {
         connected = true;
         break;
       }
     }
     if (!connected){
      //while(1);
      Serial.println("Not Connected.");
     }
     delay(1000);
     //print the ip addr

   Serial2.println("AT+CIFSR");
     Serial.println("ip address:");
     while (Serial2.available())
     Serial.write(Serial2.read());


     //set the single connection mode
     Serial2.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
   }
   void loop()
   {
    //connectWiFi();
     String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
     cmd += DST_IP;
     cmd += "\",80";
     Serial2.println(cmd);
     Serial.println(cmd);
     Serial.println(cmd);
     if(Serial2.find("Error")) return;
     cmd = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
     Serial2.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
     Serial2.println(cmd.length());
     if(Serial2.find(">"))
     {
       //dbgSerial.print(">");
       Serial.print(">");
       }else
       {
         Serial2.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
         //dbgSerial.println("connect timeout");
         Serial.println("connect timeout");
         delay(1000);
         return;
       }
       Serial2.print(cmd);
       delay(2000);
       //Serial.find("+IPD");
       while (Serial2.available())
       {
         char c = Serial2.read();
         //dbgSerial.write(c);
         Serial.write(c);
         //if(c=='\r') dbgSerial.print('\n');
         if(c=='\r') Serial.print('\n');
       }
       //dbgSerial.println("====");
       Serial.println("====");
       delay(1000);
     }
     boolean connectWiFi()
     {
       Serial2.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
       String cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
       cmd+=SSID;
       cmd+="\",\"";
       cmd+=PASS;
       cmd+="\"";
       //dbgSerial.println(cmd);
       Serial2.println(cmd);
       Serial.println(cmd);
       delay(2000);
       if(Serial2.find("OK"))
       {
         //dbgSerial.println("OK, Connected to WiFi.");
         Serial.println("OK, Connected to WiFi.");
         return true;
         }else
         {
           //dbgSerial.println("Can not connect to the WiFi.");
           Serial.println("Can not connect to the WiFi.");
           return false;
         }
       }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a hardware problem, not software.

Answer (score 0):

From the schema I can see, that device uses 3V logic (I guess it from tension divider)? In that case if you communicate with 5V logic, then you should use 5v/3v buffers on Tx and Rx. This is my guess and my advice:

> Always debug communication problems with oscilloscope.

Without this you simply cannot know what is happening.

Also make some other debugging. You assume, that device responds with `ready or Ready`, but try to print this out, what it actually really gave on output. Otherwise it's impossible for us to debug your piece of hardware without your hardware in the hands.

Also please make a note, that this is not appropriate forum for this kind of questions as there is https://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you Dawid for valuable reply.

Comment: Translation: condensators = capacitors

Answer (score -1):

Sorry @DawidPi thats not completly correct.
Yes it´s right thats not opimal to do it with a voltage divider. But this is not the problem. To solve the problem with the 3.3 TX will work (surely at 9600 baud --> I did it already like this)

Your problem is the power of your Arduino board. The ESP needs much current. Your board will not support this high current. You have to supply your ESP wih an external supply. I can recommend a fix voltage regulator like the LF33CV. Youse it with two condensators and it will work :-)

Wiring like here: [image].
If you use a LF33CV your UE should be between 4.3 and 40V. For testing I used the 5V of my USB-port. That will also work.

Try starting your ESP like this:

```
#define pin_reset 2 //Connect to RST pin of ESP8266

bool start()
{
  pinMode(PinReset, OUTPUT);
  delay(1);
  pinMode(PinReset, INPUT);

  delay(1000);
  if (Serial.find("Ready"))
  {
    delay(1000);
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first parapraph does not belong in an answer, it is a comment to another answer!

Comment: Thank you Fruchtzwerg for your good suggestions. Can you provide me you wiring diagram, how you have connected it with Arduino Mega And ESP8266.

If you can provide source code to test then will be very much appreciated.